# LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests with GPRS modem on ecos

Tags: ppp

I am using GPRS modem and want to establish connection over PPP on eCos. But it can't be dial up successfully. This modem works fine on windows xp. what causes of "LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests" could be? 
Please give suggestions.
Thanks a lot!

My chat script is as following

```
    "ABORT",        "NO CARRIER",
    "ABORT",        "ERROR",
    "ABORT",        "NO DIALTONE",
    "ABORT",        "BUSY",
    "ABORT",        "NO ANSWER",
    "",             "AT",
    "OK",           "ATS0=0",
    "OK",           "ATE0V1",                
    "OK",           "ATE1",          
    "OK",           "AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"internet\"",        
    "OK",           "ATDT*99#",
    "CONNECT",      "\\d\\c",
    NULL
```

the log is following.

```
SYSLOG 08: Using interface ppp0
SYSLOG 04: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/serial0
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x37ad5204> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 <auth chap 05>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 <auth chap 05>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x37ad5204> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 <auth chap 05>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 <auth chap 05>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x37ad5204> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 <auth chap 05>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x37ad5204> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x37ad5204> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x37ad5204> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x37ad5204> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x37ad5204> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x37ad5204> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <magic 0x37ad5204> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 10: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
SYSLOG 10: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap>]
SYSLOG 02: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
SYSLOG 04: Connection terminated, connected for 1 minutes
```

Comment: Please post your /etc/ppp/options content or the arguments used with pppd.